# How to use regular expression to extract data with html content?

Tags: asp.net, html, regex, html-parsing

I have below html content, I want extract the Id only like 31673 31672 3166 316 using regular expression.

```
<a href="/CaseMgrTesting/Pat/Summary/31673">31673</a>
<a href="/CaseMgrTesting/Pat/Summary/31672">31672</a>
<a href="/CaseMgrTesting/Pat/Summary/3166">3166</a>
<a href="/CaseMgrTesting/Pat/Summary/316">316</a>
```

I create regular expression like below, unfortunately it only return 31673 31672. I also want remove hard code like  href="/CaseMgrTesting/Pat/Summary/ and \d\d\d\d\d ,Anybody can give me correct regular expression will be greate appreciate.

```
(?<=<a\shref="/CaseMgrTesting/Pat/Summary/\d\d\d\d\d">).*(?=</a>)
```

Comment: Simple: you don't. You would use an HTML parser.

Comment: Are you trying to use regex to parse html? If so, you might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Every time you use regexes for HTML parsing, another web developer feels the sudden urge to weep silently in the corner for seven years straight.

Comment: Also, isn't trying to match up to five digits exactly? I'm still rusty on regex to talk too much about it. That might explain why you are only getting the five ones.

Comment: Like @CBredlow said: `(?<=<a\shref="/CaseMgrTesting/Pat/Summary/\d+">).*(?=</a>)`

Comment: Hi Dio, I tried your answer, it is not working. \d+ seems can not instead \d\d\d\d\d in an positive look behind, do not know way.

Answer (score 1):

Your one-stop answer is 
[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). This nifty must-have allows you to approach HTML by node. Learn it. Live it. Love it.

Comment: Thanks Wimbo!!! I believe "Html Agility Pack" is a very good way to extract data within html code. I will learn it. Actually, I pull out above question purpose is to learn Regular Expression which is make me headache but very powerfully. I hate Regular Expression many years but recently I found my genius ex-manger's code using it, 3 lines validation code cover very very complex logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a .*?>(.*)</a>
```

use this regex for this question. Its simple one try it.

Comment: Good answer. I edited your answer since you didn't indent the code, which resulted in some invisible code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this (an updated answer of regex):

```
<a .*?>(.*?)</a>
```

The important piece of this is the `?` after the `*`. This will make the `.*` (match all) non-greedy, else you will have one match at most.